# Android Studio IDE color scheme settings cannot revoke to default white background

Tags: android, background, android-studio, ide, color-scheme

I just installed the latest Android Studio beta 0.8.
Played with the Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts , changed Scheme name: from Default to 'Darcula'. So the background colour was changed to dard grey.
I don't feel comfortable with that and I changed back to Default.

Only the Editor area background revoked back to white, all other area such as Project explorer, Properties are still dark grey.

Anyway I can reset to original white background?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

> Only the Editor area background revoked back to white, all other area such as Project explorer, Properties are still dark grey.

this is because the `editor` and the `look and feel` are different views. Changing the scheme of the editor in the Android Studio does not change the theme of the other views such as Project explorer, Properties etc.

Whenever the **`Darcula`** color scheme is applied to the editor inside `File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts`, a pop-up window would prompt like below:

[image: Darcula Look and Feel]

Upon choosing `Yes`, the color scheme of all the other views is changed alongside with the editor.

So, in order to change the scheme of the `Look and Feel` back to its default white, you need to change the theme from **`Darcula`** to **`IntelliJ`** inside `File | Settings | Appearance`.

[image]

Finally, don't forget to restart the IDE for the changes to take effect!